# Предупреждение "За последнее время слишком много ваших тревог было отклонено"

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

При попытке отметить вопрос тревогой получаем сообщение:

> За последнее время слишком много ваших тревог было отклонено.

[image: скриншот ошибки]

[image: Статистика]

Подскажите, за какой период алгоритмом сайта анализируются принятые и отклоненные тревоги, и какие допустимые рамки?

Comment: Я думаю, что конкретный алгоритм вам не подскажут — иначе вы будете просто его обходить. Может быть, вы просто злоупотребляете тревогами?

Comment: @VladD а вы посмотрите что мы отметили тревогами =) на en версии даже отмечать бы не пришлось, народ быстро суетится...

Comment: @VladD Проблема не в обходе, а в понимании работы. Пример - мы видим сколько вопросов мы можем сегодня открыть/закрыть и это факт. Также хотелось бы иметь информацию и по тревогам. Иначе смысл в надписи "10 тревог осталось" ?

Comment: Мне не видно, кто что отмечает тревогой (и это хорошо, а то вдруг я злой и мстительный?) Если что, я не администратор.

Comment: @VladD самый простой пример. пользователь  написал ответ, который по сути им не является. делаем тревогу модератору, нам приходит отметка "отклонены" (тревога), а ответ пользователя удален. вот так просто мы получили одну из "отклоненных" тревог =)

Comment: @Alex по поводу такого ответа тревога модератору действительно не нужна. Достаточно "не является ответом" или "низкого качества"

Comment: @NickVolynkin: «не является ответом» можно найти либо в тревоге, либо в очереди проверок (которую ещё надо просмотреть, чтобы увидеть нужный вопрос).

Comment: @VladD я к тому, что это обычная тревога, которая не  "требует вмешательства модератора".

Comment: @NickVolynkin: А, я не знал, что есть разница. Тогда может быть в этом и причина?

Comment: @NickVolynkin конечно, однако это не решает суть проблемы, получается из-за 3-х отклоненных тревог мы ~ какое время не можем отмечать ответы или комменты тревогой, даже теми, что не требуют внимания модератора. Поэтому данный вопрос и возник.

Comment: @VladD уже подсказали алгоритм)

Comment: @Alex так "мы"  - это кто?

Comment: @Alex дайте ссылку на удаленный ответ (или хотя бы ссылку на вопрос). Интересно же :)

Comment: @Alex этот вопрос удалили до того, как вашу тревогу успели рассмотреть - скорее всего из-за этого движок пометил ее как отклоненную - ее даже никто не успел просмотреть. тут есть две категории тревог. первая - "должен быть закрыт" и "повтор". они считаются тревогами только до 500 репутации. после 500 вы получаете право голосовать за закрытие, и больше эти два пункта в счетчик тревог не включаются. вторая - "истинные" тревоги - все остальные. вы уже набрали 500 репутации, так что можете спокойно голосовать за закрытие того, чего считаете нужным - на счетчик тревог это уже не повлияет.

Comment: @PashaPash конечно, главное, что теперь известен алгоритм работы тревог =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пост на MSE: [**Allow recovery from flag hellban**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban).

Краткое резюме:

- Проверке подвергаются пользователи, у которых за последние **7 дней** было проверено **10 тревог** или более.

  - Если отклонено **>=10% тревог**, то тревоги всё ещё доступны, но пользователь видит предупреждение с предложением просмотреть свои тревоги.
  - Если отклонено **>=25% тревог**, то тревоги недоступны и пользователь видит предложение просмотреть свои тревоги.
- Если пользователь отправил меньше 10 тревог за 7 дней, но последняя тревога была отклонена, то пользователь увидит сообщение об этом и то же самое предложение просмотреть свои тревоги.

Счётчик увеличивают только тревоги на постах, которые требуют вмешательства модератора: *Другое* (призвать модератора), *Спам*, *Грубость*, *Низкое качество*, *Неверная тревога*, *Закрыть* и *Не ответ* (список может меняться по желанию левой пятки разработчиков под воздействием фазы луны).

Answer (score 3):

Все участники в разной степени наделены правами модератора и могут обрабатывать большинство запросов самостоятельно, в частности, через очереди проверок. Только исключительные ситуации действительно требуют вмешательства модератора и соответствующей тревоги:

- вандализм и "война правок"
- баги движка сайта
- подозрение на пользователя с несколькими учеными записями
- необходимость конвертировать *вопрос* в общий (ответ может конвертировать автор)
- спам в правках
- необходимость отметить закрытый вопрос как дубликат
- вредоносная правка прошла мимо роборевьюеров
- предложение объединить два совершенно идентичных вопроса
- (дополняйте)

> это не решает суть проблемы, получается из-за 3-х отклоненных тревог мы ~ какое время не можем отмечать ответы или комменты тревогой, даже теми, что не требуют внимания модератора.

Насколько я понимаю,  проблемы здесь нет. Система сработала правильно. Вы подняли несколько ошибочных тревог и получили предупреждение от системы. Оно вас обеспокоило, вы обратились на Мету и получили рекомендации о том, как правильно пользоваться тревогами. Если бы не было предупреждения, не было бы и вопроса.

Помнится мне, что там есть два уровня "штрафа": предупреждение и бан. У вас только первый и вы можете поднимать тревоги. Если вы выберете один из вариантов, синяя кнопка станет нажимаема.

Но, пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее. Отвечайте тревогой для модератора только то, что не описывается другими типами тревог и действительно требует вмешательства модератора.

Comment: @Alex ну это не страшно, пройдет. Вопрос у вас сразу о многом. На часть я ответил, а про срок не знаю. А кто эти "мы", от лица которых вы пишете?