# Вы отстранены от использования тревог - что это?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги, блокировка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На какой срок? По какой причине? Где эта информация?

Comment: так на картинке же есть ссылка специально, чтобы ты мог посмотреть какие твои тревоги были отклонены. Отстранен, очевидно, за слишком большое количество отклоненных тревог

Comment: @Grundy так я и без ссылки вижу статистику по тревогам, но как это проливает свет на ситуацию? Весьма косвенно и неполноценно

Comment: связанный вопрос [Предупреждение “За последнее время слишком много ваших тревог было отклонено”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1582/186999)

Comment: Anatol, уточните пожалуйста, что вы хотите увидеть в ответе на свой вопрос? Детальный разбор ваших тревог, которые были отклонены?

Comment: @NickVolynkin а разве в вопросе нет вопросов? Нигде не увидел пояснений к этой картинке, которые бы внесли ясность - в профиле нет информации, поиск по мете тоже толком ничего не дал

Comment: @Anatol выше Grundy дал ссылку, там есть ответы про срок и причину. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1587/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin Меня интересует срок, на который я отстранён. *Я отстранён. На какой срок?*

Comment: @Anatol считаются тревоги за последнюю неделю, пересчитываются они наверняка раз в день — точно не реже. Таким образом, если новых отклоненных тревог не будет, то блокировка пройдет не позже чем через неделю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Если считаете, что всё очевидно по этой теме, то можно удалить вопрос, но неплохо бы увидеть развёрнутый ответ. Связанный-то связанный, но тема-то отличается

Comment: @Anatol это вам решать, очевидно или нет. :) Предлагаю вам подождать неделю и последить за результатом, а потом написать ответ. Мол, «был в бане, прошло за столько-то дней». К личному опыту всегда больше доверия, чем к абстрактным рассуждениям и ссылкам.

Comment: @NickVolynkin *был в бане - в сауне лучше* :) бан чудесным образом кончился, по ощущениям продолжался несколько часов всего (точно не могу сказать), так что тут мистика

Comment: @Anatol верноятно, было так: одна или несколько тревог, данные вами за последнюю неделю, были подтверждены. Доля отклоненных стала меньше четверти, автобан снялся.